# Better way to chain rxjava2 calls with conditional operations

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have the following code, that does one single call, gets the result of the call, which is a boolean, then makes the second call if the result is false.

```
private fun linkEmailAndTextTogether(contactPhoneNumber: ContactPhoneNumbers,phoneNumber : PhoneNumber) {
    val single = SingleOnSubscribe<Boolean> {
        contactPhoneNumber.doesEmailContactExist(phoneNumber)
    }
    Single.create(single)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeWith(object : SingleObserver<Boolean> {
                override fun onSuccess(phoneNumberDoesExist: Boolean) {
                    if (!phoneNumberDoesExist) {
                        val completable = CompletableOnSubscribe {
                            contactPhoneNumber.linkEmailAndTextTogether(phoneNumber)
                        }
                        compositeDisposable.add(Completable.create(completable)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribe())
                    }
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    compositeDisposable.add(d)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(e,e.localizedMessage)
                }


            })
}
```

It seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this in some kind of chain.

Comment: Maybe similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058320/rxjava-how-to-conditionally-apply-operators-to-an-observable-without-breaking-t

Comment: That didn't really help me understand what I should do.  But thanks.

Comment: does the second return always a Boolean ?

Comment: @Blackbelt - yes

Comment: why don't you use one of the map operators then ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526978/what-rxjava-operator-to-use-to-chain-observables-only-under-certain-conditions?rq=1 this should do.

Comment: @Blackbelt - I'm new to RX java and don't exactly know how to use the map operators

Comment: @karandeepsingh I also have single and a completable - how to chain those?

Comment: Good tutorial here: https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava, also learning this stuff.

Comment: Do you need to know if the first or the second call failed?

Comment: @Blackbelt - no, they are sqlite calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the  `flatMap` operator - the downside is that you won't know if the first or the second failed.

```
  Single.just(phoneNumber)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .map { it -> contactPhoneNumber.doesEmailContactExist(it) }
       .flatMap { it ->
             if (it) {
                 return@flatMap contactPhoneNumber.linkEmailAndTextTogether(phoneNumber)
              }
              Single.just(it)
        }.subscribe({}, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
val single = SingleOnSubscribe<Boolean> {
     getSingle()
   }

   Single.create(single).map({
    if (it){
        return@map getCompleteable()
    }
    return@map Completable.complete()
})
```